# Using og:locale:alternate to list multiple countries using this language

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I support 5 languages on my website (en, fr, de, es, it). Each page has 5 URLs based on the language:

- https://mywebsite.com/en/mywebpage
- https://mywebsite.com/fr/mywebpage
- ...

I don't have specific content based on the country so an English speaking person from the US and a English speaking person from the UK will get the same content.

As I have to specify a country for og:locale, should I pick one of the country for og:locale and use og:locale:alternate to list all the other countries where this language is used?
For example, for the English webpage, should I have the following?

```
<meta property="og:locale"  content="en-US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate"  content="en-GB" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate"  content="en-CA" />
```

Or should I choose one og:locale (en-US for this example) and let Facebook do the rest?

Comment: _“[…] and let Facebook do the rest?”_ - I don’t know what “rest” you are hoping for here ... but there isn’t any mechanism to automatically show a shared link’s details in the language of the viewing user. This was a feature for Open Graph stories (has since been removed), and was never supposed to work for normal posts.

Comment: Let's try to simplify my question. In a page in English, where I expect people from different countries to visit and share, should I use og:locale:alternate to list all the English speaking country I target or picking only one (en-US for example) is enough?

Comment: Step 1: Realize this is about languages, not countries.

Comment: Well, en-US, en-GB and en-CA are three differents languages (is that Step 1?). However, I can afford to handle them all so I have only one version of English on my website (let's say it's en-US). Should I use the locale:alternate properties to list all the other languages that are close to en-US or is it useless?

Comment: You are supposed to use `locale:alternate` with _different_ URLs, otherwise that does not make much sense to begin with. The differences between those “versions” of English will be minimal in most cases anyway, so you would not provide “alternatives” anyway, and with the versions of French, German and some other languages it is quite similar. This feature is (/was) intended more for situations where you have your content in actually really different languages, say you have an English, French, German, Spanish, ... version.